# Inequality for the trace of two positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Reading through a paper on matrix factorizations, the authors use the following inequality (attributed to  Von Neumann) to prove an intermediate result:

> For all $X, Y ∈ S_d^{++}$ (d-dimensional positive definite matrices),
>   $tr(XY ) ≥ \sum_i \lambda_i \mu_i$, where where $\lambda_i$ and
>   $\mu_i$ are the eigenvalues of $X$ and $Y$ in nonincreasing and
>   nondecreasing order, respectively. The equality is attained whenever
>   $X = UDiag(\lambda)U^T , Y = UDiag(\mu)U^T$ for some orthonormal $U$.

The authors reference this paper as proof `A. W. Marshall and I. Olkin. Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and its Applications . Academic Press, 1979.` I don't have access to this publication - and it's not clear to me why this should be true.

I would appreciate if anyone could provide a proof for this statement.

Thanks.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting (since I at first misunderstood it) that in $\operatorname{Diag}(\lambda)$ and $\operatorname{Diag}(\mu)$, the $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are understood to be ordered as described in the preceding sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the piece of the following that is a little informal, but I suspect you will get the drift.  The two positive definite matrices can always be written as
$$\overline {\underline {\bf{X}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T}{\rm{   and   }}\overline {\underline {\bf{Y}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } ^T}$$
where $\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} }$ and $\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} }$ are orthonormal, while
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} }  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\lambda _1}}& \cdots &0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0& \cdots &{{\lambda _D}}
\end{array}} \right]{\rm{   and   }}\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} }  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\mu _1}}& \cdots &0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0& \cdots &{{\mu _D}}
\end{array}} \right]$$
with all ${\lambda _i}$ and ${\mu _i}$ positive and arranged in non-increasing order.  Then the properties of the trace operation permit one to write
$$\begin{array}{l}
{\rm{tr}}\left( {\overline {\underline {\bf{X}} } \,\overline {\underline {\bf{Y}} } } \right) = {\rm{tr}}\left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } }^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } }^T}} \right) = {\rm{tr}}\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } }^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } }^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } } \right)\\
{\rm{             }} = {\rm{tr}}\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} } }^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } } \right) = {\rm{tr}}\left( {{{\left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} } } \right)}^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } } \right)
\end{array}$$
where
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} }  = {\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} }  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_1}}& \cdots &{{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_D}}
\end{array}} \right]$$
remains orthonormal.  A further property of the trace operation is
$${\rm{tr}}\left( {{{\overline {\underline {\bf{A}} } }^T}\overline {\underline {\bf{B}} } } \right) = {\rm{vec}}{\left( {\overline {\underline {\bf{B}} } } \right)^T}{\rm{vec}}\left( {\overline {\underline {\bf{A}} } } \right)$$
where ${\rm{vec}}\left(  \bullet  \right)$ denotes the operation of rearranging the $D\,x\,D$ matrix into a ${D^2}\,x\,1$ vector by concatenating matrix columns, so that
$${\rm{tr}}\left( {\overline {\underline {\bf{X}} } \,\overline {\underline {\bf{Y}} } } \right) = {\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\mu _1}{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_1}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{\mu _D}{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_D}}
\end{array}} \right]^T}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_1}}\\
 \vdots \\
{\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_D}}
\end{array}} \right] = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^D {{\mu _i}\underline {\bf{w}} _i^T\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}}$$
Now, remembering that each ${\underline {\bf{w}} _i}$ is a column of an orthonormal matrix, it is not terribly difficult to see that the largest possible value of the trace is when the ${\underline {\bf{w}} _i}$ are chosen to pair the value of ${\mu _i}$ completely with the corresponding ${\lambda _i}$, since they are both in non-increasing order.  Similarly, after some thought, it is clear that the smallest possible value of the trace occurs when the ${\underline {\bf{w}} _i}$ are chosen to pair the value of ${\mu _i}$ completely with the corresponding ${\lambda _{D - i}}$ (i.e., in reverse order), so that
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^D {{\mu _i}{\lambda _{D - i}}}  \le {\rm{tr}}\left( {\overline {\underline {\bf{X}} } \,\overline {\underline {\bf{Y}} } } \right) \le \sum\limits_{i = 1}^D {{\mu _i}{\lambda _i}}$$
The maximum result occurs when
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } {\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } {\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}\overline {\underline {\bf{X}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T}{\rm{   and   }}\overline {\underline {\bf{Y}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T}$$
The minimum result occurs when
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{W}} }  = \overline {\underline {\bf{J}} }  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0& \cdots &1\\
 \vdots & {\mathinner{\mkern2mu\raise1pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu
 \raise4pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise7pt\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}} & \vdots \\
1& \cdots &0
\end{array}} \right]{\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\overline {\underline {\bf{J}} } {\rm{   }} \Rightarrow {\rm{   }}\overline {\underline {\bf{X}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{\Lambda }} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T}$$
but that
$$\overline {\underline {\bf{Y}} }  = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \left( {\overline {\underline {\bf{J}} } \,\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } \,\overline {\underline {\bf{J}} } } \right){\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T} = \underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } _r}{\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} } ^T}{\rm{   where   }}{\underline {\overline {\bf{{\rm M}}} } _r} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\mu _D}}& \cdots &0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0& \cdots &{{\mu _1}}
\end{array}} \right]$$